# How can I merge two lines to one via OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I have a tool on the map that lets the user draw a line.
Now I want to give the user the option to split the line to multiple lines, to join them back together to one line later.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Aare you asking how to split the line, put it back together, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi for spatial operations on the client side, take a look at the turf JS library, 
else deal with it server side !

[turf js](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/)

Comment: Eventually I used draw tool and did the split and merge on the server side and upon callback redrew the layer

Answer (score 1):

This might help with splitting. [split](https://github.com/stvno/openlayers/blob/master/examples/split-feature.html)

Not sure about merging lines.

Comment: Isn't this openlayers 2?